# How do you do a groupwise max in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning to use Cloud Firestore with Flutter.

Say I've got a collection called Updates:

```
{
  uid: 1234,
  update: "At work",
  date: <timestamp>
}
```

I want to get the most recent update for each user. If I have a list of users, I could do:

```
db.collection("updates")
  .where("uid", "==", $uid)
  .orderby(date desc)
  .limit(1)
  .get();
```

for each one. But how would I get a list of users from my Updates collection? Do I need to store a separate collection of users which I ensure is unique, and keep it in sync with my updates collection?

If I'm doing that, is there a good way to do the retrieval in one step, or do I have to get all the users and then iterate over them and retrieve their most recent document ID and request that document?

I'm coming from a mysql background and I think I am Doing It Wrong :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore does not offer any aggregation queries, such as sum, avg, and so on.  You will have to store this extra data in another collection, as you've already identified.  Cloud Functions is often used to automatically keep changes to documents in sync with other documents.

Cloud Firestore also does not support queries that span multiple collections with different names, nor are they any joins between collections.  If you need data from multiple collections, you will have to make multiple queries against them, and join up the results in the client.

This is all pretty typical for NoSQL type databases.

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing this up! I figured that might have been the case, and I was worried I was being a bit lazy for asking such a beginner question, but I'd read through quite a bit of material trying to find this kind of "no, you're not supposed to be able to do that" confirmation, so thanks very much for taking the time :)